# Intersection of divisors under automorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am wondering what kind of arguments does one use to prove something like this:

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and let $Y,Z$ be two prime divisors on $X$. Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be an automorphism of $X$. Then
$$Y.Z=f(Y).f(Z)$$

Comment: Dear Heitor, is $X$ supposed to be a surface here? If not it is hard to make sense of the question: in general $Y.Z$ and $f(Y).f(Z)$ will be cycles on $X$, and it is _not_ true that these two cycles are "equal", for most interpretations of "equal".

Comment: oops. Yeah, sorry. The case of surface was what I had in mind here (or maybe could I replace with: two cycles of complementary dimension?). I'll edit anyway

Comment: OK, now the question makes sense to me. (Yes, it would make sense for cycles of complementary dimension too.) Short answer: if $Y$ and $Z$ meet at an isolated point $p$ then $f(Y)$ and $f(Z)$ meet at $f(p)$; $f$ induces an isomorphism of the local ring at $p$ with the local ring at $f(p)$, and takes local definining functions for $Y$ and $Z$ to local definining functions for $f(Y)$ and $f(Z)$. So all the ingredients going into the computation of $\cdot$ at a point correspond. Now sum over all intersection points; extend to the case $Y=Z$ by the moving lemma.

Comment: Is that the kind of answer you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, dear @Asal, that's sufficient. Thank you!